# How do you make a stacked graph in a relative frequency distribution for the results of a test?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a been working on a single R homework problem for over 4 hours now and have no idea what to do, as everything I try leads to errors. The question asks to graph data on parasitic plants growing in different directions. The data consists of "count", which counts the total plants, direction, which shows the categorical direction the plant grew in (left, right, towards solvent, towards volatile material), and type, which shows if the sample is the observed lab or the expected null hypothesis.

I want to make a stacked bar plot (though I might need to do a histogram) where the observed and expected variables (which is labeled in the dataframe) are each a bar in the x-axis, y is the count of the plants that grew in each direction, and stacked fill value as the directions the plants grew in  in observed vs expected measurements. I provided an image of the data, and my plans for the graph to make answering easier.

[image]

Code:

```
ggplot(parasite, aes(x=type, y=count, fill=identity))+ geom_bar(stat'identiy')
```

Comment: `ggplot(parasite, aes(x = type, y = count, fill = direction)) + geom_col()`

Comment: To add, I'm not clear if you want a proportional stacked bar chart or not. If you do, add `position = "fill"` inside `geom_col()`.

Comment: For future posts, consider using `dput` to give an example of your data

Answer (score 1):

With `geom_bar` we could do:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(parasite, aes(x=type, y=count, fill=direction)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(x= type, y=count, label=count, group = direction),
            position = position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

data:

```
parasite <- tribble(
  ~count, ~direction, ~type,
  17, "volatile", "observed",
  2, "solvent", "observed",
  7, "left", "observed",
  4, "right", "observed",
  7, "volatile", "expected",
  7, "solvent", "expected",
  7, "left", "expected",
  7, "right", "expected"
)
```

[image]